# Как правильно настроить Aliases

Tags: php, yii, yii2

Как правильно настроить **Aliases**  в **yii2** файла конфигурации **web.php**

Судя по справочнику, его нужно указывать именно в процессе начальной загрузке, а именно в **'bootstrap'**.

вот из офф.документации:

```
return [
    // ...
    'aliases' => [
        '@foo' => '/path/to/foo',
        '@bar' => 'http://www.example.com',
    ],
];
```

---

**Пример** указания пути к файлу по URL - '@bar' => 'http://www.example.com'

**Пример** указания внутреннего пути - '@foo' => '/path/to/foo'

---

Но как aliases вставить в **bootstrap** не понятно, примера нету. Как правильно вставить **aliases** в **bootstrap**? Я так понимаю что **aliases** не нужно подключать к **'components'**, или тоже нужно?

Вот конфигурационный файл приложения:

```
<?php

$params = require(__DIR__ . '/params.php');

$config = [
    'id' => 'basic',
    'basePath' => dirname(__DIR__),
    'bootstrap' => ['log'],
    'components' => [
        'request' => [
            // !!! insert a secret key in the following (if it is empty) - this is required by cookie validation
            'cookieValidationKey' => 'o8f453525252525252525iMVKf',
        ],
        'cache' => [
            'class' => 'yii\caching\FileCache',
        ],
        'user' => [
            'identityClass' => 'app\models\User',
            'enableAutoLogin' => true,
        ],
        'errorHandler' => [
            'errorAction' => 'site/error',
        ],
        'mailer' => [
            'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
            // send all mails to a file by default. You have to set
            // 'useFileTransport' to false and configure a transport
            // for the mailer to send real emails.
            'useFileTransport' => true,
        ],
        'log' => [
            'traceLevel' => YII_DEBUG ? 3 : 0,
            'targets' => [
                [
                    'class' => 'yii\log\FileTarget',
                    'levels' => ['error', 'warning'],
                ],
            ],
        ],
        'db' => require(__DIR__ . '/db.php'),
    ],
    'params' => $params,
];

if (YII_ENV_DEV) {
    // configuration adjustments for 'dev' environment
    $config['bootstrap'][] = 'debug';
    $config['modules']['debug'] = [
        'class' => 'yii\debug\Module',
    ];

    $config['bootstrap'][] = 'gii';
    $config['modules']['gii'] = [
        'class' => 'yii\gii\Module',
    ];
}

return $config;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если алиасы нужны именно через этот конфиг, то можно их вписывать на самом верхнем уровне:

```
'params' => $params,
'aliases' => [
    '@foo' => '/path/to/foo',
    '@bar' => 'http://www.example.com',
],
```

Comment: то есть их не нужно вписывать в 'bootstrap'.? Просто вот: Корневые псевдонимы, как правило, создаются на этапе предварительной загрузки (bootstrapping).  (у меня корневой псевдоним)

Comment: А правильно ли я задаю путь?а то почему то не работает "return $this->renderFile(Yii::getAlias('@footest'));".  'aliases' => [
        '@footest' => dirname(__DIR__)."views/layouts/license.php",
    ],

Comment: В массив bootstrap их вроде не воткнуть, только через Yii::setAlias() если где-то по коду. Посмотрите что echo Yii::getAlias('@footest') кажет, там и сориентируетесь что куда подставить...

Comment: Т.е. если хочется через bootstrap, то надо создавать компонент, в нем втыкать Yii::setAlias(), а уже этот компонент вписывать в bootstrap.

Comment: Это свойство доступно таким образом, чтобы вы могли указывать псевдонимы в рамках конфигурации приложения, а не вызовов метода Yii::setAlias(). Что скажите?

Comment: Дак а что тут сказать, вам предлагают удобный способ инита алиасов через конфиг - вы его и делаете. Вы просто зачем-то хотели через bootstrap, я сказал как можно через него. )

Comment: Да, спасибо.Просто написано что - Корневые псевдонимы, как правило, создаются на этапе предварительной загрузки (bootstrapping).

Comment: -Отлично, все работает!) Спасибо еще раз!  Ну все-таки я не могу понять, зачем они пишут это - Корневые псевдонимы, как правило, создаются на этапе предварительной загрузки (bootstrapping)

Comment: Это скорее всего полезно, когда вам нужно будет в своем алиасе воспользоваться дефолтным вроде @webroot, т.е. в конфиге на момент его парса дефолтных алиасов еще не будет, тогда надо инить свой алиас через bootstrap и там заработает.

Comment: в своём алисе я использую дефолтный '@app' , получается мне нужно создавать компонент моего алиса и вызвать через bootstrap?

Comment: '@app' то как раз есть, а вот '@web' и '@webroot' еще нет

Comment: немножечко не понял что вы имеете в виду.

Comment: попробуйте в конфиге задать алиас вроде '@foo' => '@web/path/to/foo', и распечатайте его через Yii::getAlias('@foo')

Comment: минутку    ```````

Comment: вылазит ошибка Почему ? throw new InvalidParamException("Invalid path alias: $alias");

Comment: из-за этого алиса '@web' вылазит ошибка , но почему через  '@app' все нормально? Этот алисс '@web' не успевает загрузиться, и поэтому его нужно вызывать через bootstrap?

Comment: Вот о том и речь, что алиасы web/webroot создаются позже. И если вам край как надо использовать их в своем алиасе - придется где-то в коде (bootstrap компонент) задавать через Yii::setAlias(). А пока у вас все работает через '@app' - нет и причин для заморочек.

Comment: В общем эта цитата про корневые псевдонимы - она имх как раз про эти алиасы и есть, которые недоступны на момент чтения конфига.

Comment: Понятненько. Тысячу спасибок от меня, вам, за объяснения. )